# Copying one array to another using a while loop

Tags: c, arrays, while-loop

I came across the following piece of code that is supposed takes two different character arrays, copy one to another and then print them out;

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
  char a[15] = "hello";
  char b[15] = "goodbye";
  char * aa = a, *bb = b;
  while ( (*bb++ = *aa++) );
  printf("%s,%s\n",a,b);
}
```

I'm not sure how the while statement is working here. It looks like it is copying the address of b to that of a, but I really don't know the underlying workings of what is going on here. Any help understanding this would be appreciated.

Comment: A good book on C should answer this I guess ....

Comment: A book on C should also tell you that `main()` returns `int`.

Comment: For such a simple program it would be a good idea to simply simulate the behaviour on paper or step through it in a debugger. This should reveal the logic behind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Things to know:

- `*aa` dereferences the pointer `aa`, so accesses the element `aa` is pointing to right now
- `aa++` increments `aa` by one. as `aa` is a pointer, it now points to the **next** element. This happens **after** evaluation.
- a **string** in C always ends with a `0` byte.
- in a **boolean** context, `0` is *false* and any other value is *true*
- an **assignment** evaluates to the value that was assigned.

So, when walking through your strings, eventually `*aa` will be `0` (the end of the string), which makes the whole expression `(*bb++ = *aa++)` have the value of `0` -- inside the `while` condition, this is false, causing the loop to exit.

Comment: Cool thanks I'll have another look now, I had never read about dereferencing before, I clearly have a lot to learn. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Good! don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your problem